# am I using correctly "doesn't" and "are"?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm taking course in english (not my mother language).
I'm writing a report but I have a problem in how to use the `does` and `are`. Which is the correct way to write this:

1. The null values **aren't** too many maybe drop de null values doesn't affect too much de analysis.

or

2. The null values **doesn't are** too many maybe drop de null values doesn't affect too much de analysis.

or maybe none. I don't know why but I'm not sure how write this sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'there' as a [dummy subject](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects) to indicate the existence (or non-existence) of something.

"There are not too many null values."

(You need a subject for 'doesn't affect' as well. I would also use future tense ('won't') because you haven't dropped them yet)

Answer (score 0):

As Evene says in their answer above using "there" as a dummy subject allows you to use "aren't" correctly.

"There aren't too many" is perfectly good English but a little bit informal. But "doesn't are" is not English at all.

You can say "The data set *doesn't have* many null values" but "doesn't" only works with the verb "to be" in very rare cases if at all.

By the way the definite article is 'the' not 'de'.